# Ignore timeout error while executing a javascript automation script on OSX

Tags: macos, javascript-automation

While converting a document to another document , my script (written in javascript in the Script Editor on OSX 10.10) times out with an error -1712 ("AppleEvent Timed Out").

How can ignore this timeout? Or at least extend the timeout delay.

Comment: For clarity's sake: it is a Keynote document. The conversion runs fine for other exporttypes because they take less long to convert. No modal dialogs etc. pop up; only a progress-window as per usual is shown.

Answer (score 0):

I found this paragraph inside the Javascript for Automation documentation [Timeout, Considering, and Ignoring](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/InterapplicationCommunication/RN-JavaScriptForAutomation/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014508-CH109-SW36)! You shall pass `{ timeout: 600 }` as last parameter to function calls.

Comment: Looks like the current link is here: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/InterapplicationCommunication/RN-JavaScriptForAutomation/Articles/OSX10-10.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014508-CH109-SW36